# Add bounty expiration date/time to tab in profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, profile-page

Really minor thing, but on the active bounty tab in a user's profile, it would be nice to see when they expire without needing to visit individual questions.  I know there are other notifications about this, but having them in one place would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops, these *used* to be there but somewhere along the way a few bugs slipped in, preventing them from showing up.  They'll be back in working order with the next build.